# Strange resetting of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have this functions:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *) getUserDataDictionary
{
    [userDataDicionary removeAllObjects];
    userDataDicionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self getUserDataDictionaryPath]];

    return userDataDicionary;   
}

- (int) getIndexOfLastVehicle
{
MyAppDelegate *app = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableDictionary *tmpUserData = [app getUserDataDictionary];

int lastHighestIndex = -1;

for(id item in [tmpUserData allKeys]){
    NSString *keyInArray = (NSString *)item;

    if ([keyInArray rangeOfString:@"VEHICLE-"].location != NSNotFound) {
        //f.e. "VEHICLE", "1", "TYPE"...or "VEHICLE", "1", "SPZ"...or "VEHICLE", "2", "TYPE" etc
        NSArray * separatedComponents = [keyInArray componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
        int indexOfVehicle = [(NSString *)[separatedComponents objectAtIndex:1] intValue];

        if(indexOfVehicle > lastHighestIndex){
            lastHighestIndex = indexOfVehicle;
        }
    }
}

return lastHighestIndex;
}
```

The problem is:
after this code:

```
MyAppDelegate *app = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableDictionary *tmpUserData = [app getUserDataDictionary];

int lastVehicleIndex = [self getIndexOfLastVehicle];
```

The tmpUserData is EMPTY.

But when I changed order to this:

```
int lastVehicleIndex = [self getIndexOfLastVehicle];

MyAppDelegate *app = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableDictionary *tmpUserData = [app getUserDataDictionary];
```

The tmpUserData is correctly filled.

Can someone explain this behavior?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of you problems lies in the method `getUserDataDictionary`. You are calling `removeAllObjects` which does not releases the userDataDictionary. You have to release it instead of removingAllObject. The actual release will release all it's objects for you.

Comment: Yes, this was problem. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from being a pro in Objective C, but the other I had a similar problem with az NSMutableArray. The problem in my case was that something got released or inited one more time than required.

I suggest putting a few NSLog()-s here and there to find out where your content goes lost. I did this, I basically put an NSLog to each and every instruction involving my object, and finally I was able to fix the stuff.

Just an idea, probably it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in this method:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *) getUserDataDictionary
{
    [userDataDicionary release]; 
    userDataDicionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self getUserDataDictionaryPath]];

    return userDataDicionary;   
}
```

Comment: BTW According to Apple's coding convention there is a rule to name property setters as 'setProperty' and getters as 'property' therefore it is better to rename the method to userDataDictionary